# How to call silence! on dalli cache_store?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dalli

I'm trying to develop application with caching in development mode, but development.log spammed is heavily by cache logs. I'm use dalli, and I know, that dalli has silence! method (https://github.com/mperham/dalli/commit/892020fbc73613ccc84412ce04b85b7fda645e63), but how to use this method?

I found some old instructions, where it is suggested to call in on `config.cache_store`, but it is a symbol, and don't has this method:

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
config.cache_store.silence!
```

Throws exception.

Comment: I'm now also using https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets gem.

Comment: but doesn't quiet_assets deal with completely different things from the cache log?

Comment: Of course. This option anq quiet_assets gem works in pair to keep logs clean from noise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try calling `#silence!` on `Rails.cache`

Comment: Great, I put it into config/environment.rb and it works. Thanks!